# How to invoke Generic Method with Generic Parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, sqlite-net

I would like to know how to use reflection in C# to call the following method :

```
public static List<T> GetAllWithChildren<T>
    (this SQLiteConnection conn, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, bool recursive = false) 
    where T
    #if USING_MVVMCROSS: new() #else : class #endif
    {
    }
```

My current code is:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(ReadOperations).GetMethod("GetWithChildren", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
Type predicateType = predicate.GetType();
MethodInfo genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(predicateType);
Type[] genericArgumentsType = genericMethod.GetGenericArguments();
Debug.WriteLine("Arguments Number:" + genericArgumentsType.Count());
int count = 0;
foreach (Type ga in genericArgumentsType)
{
    Console.WriteLine(count++ + " " + ga.GetType());
}
Object[] genericArguments = { conn, predicate, true };
genericMethod.Invoke(conn, genericArguments);
```

The number of arguments returned is 1 ... that it's wrong but I don't know why the system return to me this number.

The invoke method fail with a wrong number of arguments.

Any help will be welcome!

Comment: The number of _generic arguments_ is one (`T`).  The number of _parameters_ is 3 (`SQLiteConnection conn`, `Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter` and `bool recursive`).  You can get the parameters by calling `GetParameters`.

Comment: Also note that `predicateType` will be `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` which is NOT the proper type to use when calling `MakeGenericMethod`.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the Predicate's Generic argument to Make the method generic. which means:

Generic argument of `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` would be `Func<T, bool>` which is not actual type you're looking for to mark the method with. Update the following lines:

```
Type predicateType = predicate.GetType();
MethodInfo genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(predicateType);
```

To

```
Type parameterType = predicate.Parameters[0].Type;
MethodInfo genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(parameterType);
```

This will give you the type of `T` from `Func<T,bool>`. Now It should work as expected.

Above change are based on assumption that you're predicate is of type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. In case the predicate is `Func<T, bool>` then parameterType can be fetched like below:

```
Type parameterType  = predicate1.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Comment: Any time i see `MakeGenericMethod` all i see is HULK SMASH. Microsoft needs to fix this insanity api

Answer (score 1):

You're calling it with GetWithChildren, instead of GetAllWithChildren.

Answer (score 0):

your generic method is extension method....Change below code and try again

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(**SQLiteConnection**).GetMethod("GetAllWithChildren", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
```